# Angular - always get "[Object object]" errors on a request (even if request works)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I'm facing a strange issue on my angular app:

I've created a registration form component, which sends - using a service method - an http post request to the server with registration data.

 If registration went fine, it returns a string, otherwise it returns a bad request.

**THE PROBLEM:**

Now, the problem is that even if registration goes fine (my db table is filled and the user is created), my registration http method Always runs through "error" section of http request method.

The error simply says "[Object object]" and my service returns the "Account created" string as success response

Why does it always throws an error? How can I solve this issue?

---

I share with you my code below:

> REGISTRATION COMPONENT .ts - Register method

```
registerUser({ value, valid }: { value: UserRegistration, valid: boolean }) {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.isRequesting = true;
    this.errors='';
    if(valid)
    {
        this.userService.register(value.email,value.password,value.firstName,value.lastName,value.location)
                  .finally(() => this.isRequesting = false)
                  .subscribe(
            result => {
                console.log(result);
                if (result) {                      
                        this.router.navigate(['/login']);                         
                    }},
            errors => { console.error(errors); this.errors = errors });
    }      
 }
```

> REGISTRATION SERVICE METHOD - http request

```
register(email: string, password: string, firstName: string, lastName: string, location: string): Observable<any> {
        let body = JSON.stringify({ email, password, firstName, lastName, location });
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')

        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/Accounts/NewUser", body, { headers })
            .map(res => { return true })
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error));  //ALWAYS PASSES THROUGH HERE
    }
```

> MY API

```
[HttpPost("NewUser")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> NewUser([FromBody]RegistrationViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var userIdentity = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(model);

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userIdentity, model.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded) return new BadRequestObjectResult(Errors.AddErrorsToModelState(result, ModelState));

            await _appDbContext.Customers.AddAsync(new Customer { IdentityId = userIdentity.Id, Location = model.Location });
            await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new OkObjectResult("Account created");
        }
```

Comment: Take a look into the network tab of your devtools and investigate what the api returned

Comment: @Marv it returns me just an "Account created" string (tested right now)

Comment: @SantaCloud Can you print to console and expand the object in the console tab?

Comment: @RahulSaha do you mean the error object or the object returned by the API?

Comment: The error object

Comment: @RahulSaha console doesn't print me anything both if i log the result and the error, both in the service and the user registration component. This is strange... Have you got any idea?

Comment: Doesn't print? Can you create a plunker and share the link?

Comment: @RahulSaha I've solved but I absolutely don't understand why. I explain you how, maybe you will understand better than me. From the service, I return a Ok (no more an OkObjectResult) boolean true in case of success: `return new Ok(true);`. On my component, I've commented the "finally". In my service, I return an  `Observable<boolean> ` instead an observable of type any. Still in my service, I've changed the ".map" content with: ` .map(res => { if (res) { return true; } })` . Now it works. What could it be?

Comment: you are mapping response of your post to always true, that is probably why is your catch ignored